# Query / Ping a website to display website online status

Tags: web, offline

Alright so I'm trying to figure out a way to query a websites online status so that it displays on my main hub website the online status of that particular website.

For example, I'm looking for it to look like:

Websites:
www.google.com - **ONLINE or OFFLINE**
...
...

The "..." would be the other sites of course and after the "-" would either say Online or Offine...

I'm googled this but can't find anything specific on how to do this with websites, just Minecraft servers

Answer (score 0):

I found several sites explaining how to do this
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/98433173/links.html